# How do I remove all the spawner in Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My game is full of villagers. I can't kill them all because my game is laggy, but I believe it's because of the monster spawner.

How do I remove the monster spawner in Minecraft?

(Version is 0.12.0 build 7)

Comment: Have you tried copying the world to your computer, editing it with MCEdit (not 2.0, the latest 1.x.x version) and then reuploading it back to your Android device?

Comment: Villagers don't spawn from monster spawners unless you created one yourself. If the MCPE mechanics are the same as the PC edition, they would be breeding because there are too many houses in the village. Try destroying all the doors and they should stop spawning.